# Vue 3/Laravel POST http://localhost:5173/register 404 (Not Found) when create AxiosClient

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-mix-vue3

When I try to register a new user I get an error back with axios.

[image]

This is my axios configuration and code where I want to use it:

##### `Axios.js`

```
import axios from "axios";
import store from "./store";

const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://localhost:5173/`,
});

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${store.state.user.token}`;

    return config;
});

export default axiosClient;
```

##### `Store/index.js`

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import axiosClient from "../axios";

const store = createStore({
    state: {
        user: {
            data: {},
            token: sessionStorage.getItem("TOKEN"),
        },
    },
    getters: {},
    actions: {
        register({ commit }, user) {
            return axiosClient.post("/register", user)
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    commit("setUser", data);

                    return data;
                });
        },
        login({ commit }, user) {
            return axiosClient.post("/login", user)
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    commit("setUser", data);

                    return data;
                });
        },
    },
```

Also I don't know why, but by deafult I have `#` in my page url:
`http://localhost:5173/#/register`

Answer (score 0):

Since a user that has not yet been authenticated in your **Login** and **Register** endpoints can send a request, you should not send the `Authorization` parameter in the header for requests made to them.
Here's how you can update your `axios.js` file with and without auth for to divide in two requests can be post:

> Note: don't put `/` at the end of the **URL** (*depending on your usage*) even if you don't have or have a prefix.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import store from "./store";

const defaultPort = '5173';
const defaultLocalHostnames = [
    '127.0.0.1',
    'localhost'
];

const hostname = defaultLocalHostnames.includes(window.location.hostname) ?
    window.location.hostname + ':' + defaultPort :
    window.location.hostname;
const apiEndPoint = `${window.location.protocol}//${hostname}`;

/**
 * For Auth. Req. Routes
 */
const auth_req = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${apiEndPoint}/your-prefix-if-exists`,
});

auth_req.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    config.headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${store.state.user.token}`,
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };
    return config;
});

/**
 * For Guest Routes
 */
const no_auth_req = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${apiEndPoint}/your-prefix-if-exists`,
});

no_auth_req.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    config.headers = {
        'Accept': '*/*',
    };
    return config;
});

export default {
    authRequired: auth_req,
    noAuthRequired: no_auth_req
};
```

Now you can use either one to fulfill your requests in `store/index.js`. For example:

```js
login({ commit }, user) {
    return axiosClient.noAuthRequired.post('/login', user).then(({ data }) => {
        commit('setUser', data);
        return data;
    });
},
```

Finally run:

> npm run dev `OR` npm run watch

Just in case, delete your old compiled files (chunks) before running them.
If you need to clear the cache on the server side, don't forget:

> php artisan optimize:clear
> php artisan route:cache

Basically, determining whether the routes you are accessing requires auth and sending parameters in the header accordingly will solve your problem.

Comment: Now I have error in consol "authRequired.post is not a function". I only add authRequired  ` 
   `actions: {
    register({ commit }, user) {
      return authRequired.post("register", user).then(({ data }) => {
        commit("setUser", data);
        return data;
      });
    },
    login({ commit }, user) {
      return authRequired.post("login", user).then(({ data }) => {
        commit("setUser", data);
        return data;
      });
    },
  },`

Comment: Each object you create with `axios.create` contains **POST** method or other axios methods covered by `axios`. You should be able to use `authRequired` and `noAuthRequired` objects when you create them as I specified in the code snippet and export them with `export default`. If you could share how you updated your code snippet I might be able to help more.

Comment: I am doing this project for practise https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLQDpY7lOLg and ia have the same code like in video. And what you mean by updated?